# Class inheritance with empty subclasses

Tags: oop, object, inheritance

Suppose I have a class modeling expense items, named Expense.  We have transportation, food, and wage expenses.  Let's say that all of the properties are the same, so there is only the one Expense class, with a "type" property.  However, let's say I add a new type of expense, called training, and this requires some new fields about the type of training, location, and date occurred.  Additionally, there are a couple new methods specific to this training expense.  So at this point, I need to subclass the Expense class so that I can have a TrainingExpense class.  As the subclass is now defining the type of expense, does this make it redundant to have a "type" property in the Expense base class?  Should I now just subclass the Expense base class for every different type?  Or should I just leave the "type" property in the base class and have it be redundant for any subclasses?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of inheritance I would use composition here. Create a property say **ExpenseExtension** of type interface `IExpenseExtension` in the base class.

For the expense types that have extra properties/methods inherit from IExpenseExtension and add the extra properties/methods needed. In the TravelExpense case it will have a `TravelExpenseExtension` class that inherits from IExpenseExtension with the extra properties/methods you need.

In the base class instantiate the appropriate `ExpenseExtension` class based on the `ExpenseType` Property.

Using composition instead of inheritance here will make it more flexible.

I would also suggest you to create an enum with all the types and use it for the ExpenseType property.

Check below Url to read about composition vs inheritance:

http://lostechies.com/chadmyers/2010/02/13/composition-versus-inheritance/

From the link:
Favoring object composition over class inheritance helps you keep each class encapsulated and focused on one task. **Your classes and class hierarchies will remain small and will be less likely to grow into unmanageable monsters.**

UPDATE:
See below code example in C#:

```
public class Expense
{
    public string Food { get; set; }

    public ExpenseType Type { get; set; }

    private IExpenseExtension expenseExtension;

    public IExpenseExtension ExpenseExtension
    {
        get
        {
            if(expenseExtension == null)
            {
                // Logic to instantiate the correct Extension based on Type property.
                // You can use Factory design pattern or something like that for this as well.
            }

            return expenseExtension;
        }
    }
}

public interface IExpenseExtension
{

}

public class TrainingExpenseExtension : IExpenseExtension
{
    public string Location { get; set; }

    public void GetTrainingDetails()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Thx, I really like that solution.  But what would I do about the extra methods as well?

Comment: Same thing. Add it to the ExpenseExtension class. Use name Extension instead of Fields so call it IExpenseExtension and TravelExpenseExtension.

Comment: I just updated the answer to say Extension instead of Fields but you can choose the name you like.

Comment: Adarsh, I want to thank you again for making me much more aware of composition over inheritance.  However, some articles mention that the simplest acid test is whether the relationship refers to an "IS a" vs "HAS a".  In this case, training IS an expense no?  Rather than an expense HAS training?  I guess it makes more sense as Expense HAS ExpenseExtensions, but in that case, when would inheritance ever be preferred?

Comment: Since you can also instantiate Expense directly and it's not an abstract class it makes more sense to go with composition. (though this rule doesn't apply always). Using inheritance will complicate things in your scenario. Inheritance is better in other places like say you have an AnimalBase(abstract class) and have Mammal and Bird as the child classes.

Comment: IS-a vs HAS-a rule is good rule to determine whether to use inheritance vs composition but you should interpret it depending on your situation. Same as you interpreted that Expense has ExpenseExtension makes more sense in your situation than TrainingExpense is an expense.

Comment: Regarding a base class that is not abstract, when would it NOT make sense to go with composition?

Comment: as the IExpenseException has not declared methods, would this be considered a "Marker Interface"?

Answer (score 1):

Another approach might be define an IExpense interface, and then implement, so all your "standard" behaviours are accessed through the interface and the special behaviours via the class. Composition approach like blacktie24's but inverted. All depends on how you are going to access the extra stuff.